# Can I get the current RAM usage in contract?

Tags: smart-contract, ram

I want to calculate the ram usage when I conduct an action in contract, if ram is over the limit, I will let the action fail automatically.

How can I get the current ram usage in contract?

Answer (score 1):

From [`resource_limits.cpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/libraries/chain/resource_limits.cpp#L164), it seems like in `eosio` code, they use `_db` to retrieve the resource consumption, which needs access to the chainbase database running.

As far as I know, this cannot be accessed from smart contract directly, thus, assuming all RAM usage for your contract can be tracked, two suboptimal solutions would be:

- Calculate the RAM consumption every time by iterating through all the table entries paid for by the account, and estimating the costs based on the data stored in each row (possibly infeasible during one transaction;)
- Keep the RAM costs in a singleton by updating it for every new entry in the table, so it doesn't have to iterate through all tables every time (for already deployed contracts, it needs an action to calculate existing RAM or just pass it as an inital value based on `cleos get account` data)

Interested in hearing about better solutions as well.

Comment: However, when you transfer money to others through your smart contract, you can't know how much ram you paid for others, because they can consume your ram by their code

Comment: @JimmyGuo yeah perhaps you could have the contract not interact directly with any contracts you don't control, though that may be a pain